# Dropbox SSL Certificate issue on OS X in both Chrome and Safari

Tags: macos, dropbox, ssl

Currently unable to connect to www.dropbox.com via https. This is only happening on one machine on the network. The machine is running OS X 10.6.8.

Safari gives -

[image]

When trying to connect in chrome I get the error below, Date and Time are correctly set. Any thoughts??

[image]

Comment: if the image would clarify, post it to imgur etc & someone can lift it in for you. What happens if you try http, not https to 108.160.165.147 & then sign in?

Comment: Imgur link for Safari - http://imgur.com/E0wR2fP

Comment: Imgur link for Chrome - http://imgur.com/vTRgm4F

Comment: With Safari - it's possible to select continue and then login but with Chrome it's just completely blocked. Using 108.160.165.147 it just redirects to https.

Comment: I inlined the pics for you, but I don't have the rep to do it directly, so someone else will need to approve my changes. If you don't like what I did you can always edit or revert it yourself, afterwards.

Comment: BTW, I can also generate the same error in Safari if I try to go to https at 108.160.165.147 but not if I use the dropbox menu bar or go to dropbox.com